# AWS EC2 Wamp 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wamp

I have wamp running on my aws locally, and my localhost is running properly on aws machine. the problem comes when i try to access the wamp server running on aws from my pc's chrome. i have done all the possible changes to remove the "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server" error. still i cant have access to it from externally. what else am i missing? can any one suggest any tutorial? i have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wnxe6JqNhvM and this is what exactly i want to do.

Comment: The tutorial is about 5 years old, so there are bound to be some inconsistencies. Have you tried opening up the EC2 Instance's security group on the port that you're trying to access?

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer are you using?

Comment: This [answer here may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922866/apache-forbidden-error-wamp/41971386#41971386)